# Using WITH and UNION to compute number of flights and weather condition with two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table A

| date | flight | airport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | ATL, GA |
| 2012-10-01 | oneway | LAX, CA |
| 2012-10-02 | oneway | SAN, CA |
| 2012-10-02 | oneway | DTW, MI |
| 2012-10-03 | round | SFO, CA |
| 2012-10-04 | round | SFO, CA |
| 2012-10-05 | round | SFO, CA |

Table B

| date | temp | precip |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-10-01 | 27 | 0.02 |
| 2012-10-02 | 35 | 0.00 |
| 2012-10-03 | 66 | 0.18 |
| 2012-10-04 | 57 | 0.00 |
| 2012-10-05 | 78 | 0.24 |

Table A has about 100k rows and whereas Table B has only about 60 rows

I am trying to query to find total number of flights on cold days and warm days as well as tracking the number of days for either cold or warm.

A cold day is defined when temp from Table B is below (<) 40 and warm otherwise.

In the real data, I have total 10 days that matches the date therefore I need to count for that when aggregating. I tried to get the total count without using CTE but I am keep getting wrong counts.

The expected outcome

| Days | Num_of_flight | Num_of_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cold day | 4 | 2 |
| warm day | 3 | 3 |

Comment: What if for the same day there are 2 rows in TableB with temp 39 and 41? Is the day cold or warm?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It was my mistake there is no overlap of days in TableB. I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of `TableB` to `TableA` and aggregation on the result of a `CASE` expression which returns `'cold'` or `'warm'`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN b.temp < 40 THEN 'cold day' ELSE 'warm day' END Days,
       COUNT(*) Num_of_flight,
       COUNT(DISTINCT a.date) Num_of_days
FROM TableB b LEFT JOIN TableA a
ON a.date = b.date
GROUP BY Days;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Xrwiw3VB).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this on the actual data but I am getting a table that is only showing one aggregated row and the output is warm day|7|5. It appears that it is actually adding all up.

Comment: @meancomu you can see in the demo that the query is returning your expected results. If it does not work with your actual data this means that either you are not using it as it is or you did not explain your requirement correctly.

Comment: Solved the issue. Thank you for answering!